# Python - How to convert .txt/.csv file holding table schema to .avsc file

Tags: python-2.7, avro, avsc

Need to extract table schema (using describe\list columns)  into .txt or .csv file and later want to convert those files into .avsc(avro schema) file using python.

sample.txt:

### COLUMN_NAME         |TYPE_NAME|DEC&|NUM&|COLUM&|COLUMN_DEF|CHAR_OCTE&|IS_NULL&

AIRLINE             |CHAR     |NULL|NULL|2     |NULL      |4         |NO
AIRLINE_FULL        |VARCHAR  |NULL|NULL|24    |NULL      |48        |YES

Need to convert sample.txt into sample.avsc

Comment: If we have a list of columns and data type ,can we create .avsc file from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read CSV into python dict
2. Get header part to other dict(header_dict)
3. create empty dict(final_dict) and append type,namespace reletad thing and pass rows from header_dict to this final_dict.
4. Dump final_dict to file, which will be your avsc